# Regular relational operator '<' not working as expected awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file like this:

```
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2024
0.2025
0.2027
0.2027
0.2029
0.2059
0.2059
0.2059
0.2059
0.2099
0.2099
0.2099
0.2105
0.2113
0.2113
0.2195
0.2198
0.2206
0.2206
0.2206
0.2989
0.2989
0.2989
0.3
0.3
```

And I would like to count the number of values which are included in a range, eg.:

```
0.2 18
0.21 5
0.22 3
0.23 0
0.24 0
0.25 0
0.26 0
0.27 0
0.28 0
0.29 3
0.3 2
```

As you can see, I use an interval of 0.01. I'm using `awk` to achieve it but I am getting some weird behavior:

```
awk 'BEGIN {for (i=0;i<1.01;i+=0.01) a[i]=0} {
    for (j=0;j<=1;j+=0.01) 
      if($1>=j && $1<j+0.01) {
        a[j]+=1
      }
    } 
    END {for (k=0;k<1.01;k+=0.01) print k,a[k]}' test_OH.txt
```

Result:

```
0.19 6
0.2 12
0.21 5
0.22 3
0.23 0
0.24 0
0.25 0
0.26 0
0.27 0
0.28 0
0.29 5
0.3 0
```

Anyone could help me? I guess `<` is not working as expected because it satisfies when `$1 == j+0.01`. Surely, I am not considering something. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Quasímodo I'll see it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -v s=0.2 -v e=0.3 -v d=0.01 '
   BEGIN { m = 1/d }
   { a[int($1*m)]++ }
   END{ e *= m; for(s = int(s*m); s <= e; s++) print s*d, a[s]+0 }
' test_OH.txt

0.2 18
0.21 5
0.22 3
0.23 0
0.24 0
0.25 0
0.26 0
0.27 0
0.28 0
0.29 3
0.3 2
```

The `s` (start) `e` (end) and `d` (delta/step) variables can be adjusted as needed.

---

1. generating a range by repeatingly adding `0.01` is almost a textbook example of what NOT to do with floating point numbers, because the `0.01` cannot be represented exactly in base 2, and the error will accumulate with each addition.
2. scanning the entire range for each line is inefficient and pointless.
3. variables in awk don't have to be initialized to `""` or `0`.

Comment: Hold on, what does the "wiggle" value do here? Slight rounding up to combat FP inaccuracy where 0.3 is actually something like 0.299999?

Comment: Instead of `$1/d` etc., try `$1*(1/d)` (brackets necessary) to avoid the use of "wiggle"

Comment: @ilkkachu it was for when `.3/.1` is `2.9999...` instead of `3`. Changed the division to a multiplication, as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {for (i=0;i<1.01;i+=0.01) a[i]=0}
  {
    n = int($1 * 100) / 100
    a[n] += 1
  }
  END {for (k=0;k<1.01;k+=0.01) print k,a[k]}'
```

or this, which I find less comprehensible:

```
awk 'BEGIN {for (i=0;i<1.01;i+=0.01) a[i]=0} {
    for (j=0;j<=1;j+=0.01)
      if(("X" $1 >= "X" j) && ("X" $1 < "X" j+0.01)) {
        a[j]+=1
      }
    }
    END {for (k=0;k<1.01;k+=0.01) print k,a[k]}'
```

For the reason why the original didn't work, see Quasimodo's remark above.

Comment: care to add at least some explanation as to why this should work and the code in the question doesn't?

Comment: Sure, I'll give another working one, you'll understand awk's preference for strings and problems comparing strings with numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much @GerardH.Pille I will use the first attempt because the second is less intuitive. It is good to know that such things can occur.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I should post this as an answer or a comment, but here's a short demonstration of the inaccuracy and the resulting numbers in this case, on my machine:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { d = 0.01; printf "%.20f\n", d; for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) a += d; printf "%.20f\n%.20f\n", 0.3, a }'   
0.01000000000000000021
0.29999999999999998890
0.30000000000000009992
```

The first number is what 0.01 actually gets stored as, it's not accurate since 1/100 includes a factor 1/5 and that can't be represented in binary.

Second is what 0.3 gets stored as, and the third is 0.01 added to itself 30 times. (That's not even the same as `0.01 * 30` because there's intermediate rounding in every step, I suppose.)

Other answers have solutions, go upvote them.